# How to debug : Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I am loading CSV data into mysql and replacing a value from a column with its corresponding value from another existing table.

I am doing this using a sub query which is supposed to always return a single value, but it turns out that this table did not have the referenced column be unique. And having duplicate values on the referenced column makes the sub query return multiple values, which is understandable.

Is there anyway to tell MySql to be more expressive about which line in the loading faze triggered this error ? or any way of debugging this issue ?

I want to find the lines in the current table that reference rows that have duplicate columns, so I would be able to manually check each one of the duplicates to make sure I reference the right data from the first table.

Example SQL

```
LOAD DATA
LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv'
REPLACE INTO
TABLE `db`.`table`
CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
#ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(
 @old_value
)
SET
`column` = (
    SELECT new_column from `db`.`other_table`
    where old_column = @old_value
);
```

Comment: Do you want to make sure sub-query won't return more than one result or do you want to find the duplicates. You are kind of asking one question and expecting an answer to another, it seems to me.

Comment: @marekful updated with what I expect from the answers. Thank you

Comment: To me this question is just a simple detection of duplicates. There are quite a number of questions on SO on this topic. Have you tried any of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to tell MySql to be more expressive about which line in the loading faze triggered this error ?

Not that I know of.

> or any way of debugging this issue ?

Look at the last record added to "db.table", find that in your datafile. The record causing the problem is the next one.

But that doesn't actually fix your issue - evidently you have not defined db.other_table.old_column to be unique **and** your insert trigger does not handle multiple records.

Since we don't know anything more about your data model, we can't really advise which of these you need to fix - but there are several answers here on how to find duplicates in a MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just doing the `LOAD DATA` statement, and then doing a separate bona fide update to map the values:

```
UPDATE `db`.`table` t1
INNER JOIN `db`.`other_table` t2
    ON t1.`column` = t2.old_column
SET t1.`column` = t2.new_value;
```

Comment: I admit that this method has its merits. The only trouble is that the column itself has changed types and was split in to two so as to be polymorphic. Also this is a little off topic

Comment: Putting a query into a `LOAD DATA` statement actually strikes me as more off topic than what I suggested.

Comment: The proposed answer does not tackle the duplicates issue

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI If you can update your question and show data which makes clear what the duplicates are, then I might be able to give you an updated query as well.